# Como hacer que la animacion sea lenta

Tags: jquery

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente codigo utilize la libreria JQuery y necesito alentar la animacion de la escritura de la animacion quiero que se vea lenta pero no demasiada, alguien sabe como se podria hacer eso? o conocen una parte de la docs deJquery para poder hacerlo?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Text</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/typed.js/1.1.4/typed.min.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
  .write{
   font-size: 22px;
  }
  .container{
   text-align: center;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <span class="write"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
        $(".write").typed({
            strings: ["Bienvenidos a A nuestra  web", "Gracias por visitar nuestra Web"],
            typeSpeed: 4,
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Uso la libreria Jquery y  typed.JS

Comment: ¿qué significa "alentar" la animación?

Comment: Perdon ,me  equivoque era "Como hacer que la animacion sea lenta

" perdon ya la edite correctamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente escribe un valor de typeSpeed un poco más alto, en múltiplos de 100 diría yo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Text</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/typed.js/1.1.4/typed.min.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
  .write{
   font-size: 22px;
  }
  .container{
   text-align: center;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <span class="write"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
        $(".write").typed({
            strings: ["Bienvenidos a A nuestra  web", "Gracias por visitar nuestra Web"],
            typeSpeed: 300,
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu ayuda.

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, ya sabes que puedes hacer (marcarla como aceptada).